# How can I output a dictionary in a class?

Tags: python

So I got a class like this:

```
class Useraccount():

def __init__(self, saving, checking, PIN):
    self.save = saving
    self.check = checking
    self.passwd = PIN
```

I want a output like this:

```
>>> a = Useraccount(2000,3000,1234)
>>> a
>>> {1234:[2000,3000]}
```

How to achieve this, please help me out.

Comment: If you want to make a dict, why did you write a class instead?

Answer (score 1):

Other answers modify `__repr__`, which only affects the string representation. To actually output a dictionary, you can define a method within UserAccount that returns in the specific format:

```
class UserAccount(object):

    def __init__(self, saving, checking, PIN):
        self.save = saving
        self.check = checking
        self.passwd = PIN

    def asDict(self):
        return {self.passwd: [self.save, self.check]}
```

For example:

```
>>> user1 = UserAccount(10, 20, 1234)
>>> user1.asDict()
{1234: [10, 20]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `__repr__` method on the Class that formats it's print output.

```
class Useraccount():

    def __init__(self, saving, checking, PIN):
        self.save = saving
        self.check = checking
        self.passwd = PIN

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Useraccount({pin}: [{saving}, {checking}])>'.format(pin=self.passwd, saving=self.save, checking=self.check)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = Useraccount(2000,3000,1234)
>>> a
<Useraccount(1234: [2000, 3000])>
```

Answer (score 0):

so, if you are using Python2.x then you should override the **unicode** method to represent a object of your Useraccount class.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '{%d: [%d,%d]}' % (self.save, self.check, self.passwd)
```

and if u are using Python3.x

```
def __str__(self)
    return '{%d: [%d,%d]}' % (self.save, self.check, self.passwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be doing what you describe:

```
class Useraccount(object):
    def __new__(cls, save, check, pin):
        return {saving: [check, pin]}
```

Example:

```
a = Useraccount(2000, 3000, 1234)
a

Out[53]: {2000: [3000, 1234]}
```

Not sure if it's a good practice though :)